# How to set state inside a loop with a time delay in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was trying to make a program to visualize bubble sort in ReactJS for which I'm trying to update the state of array inside a loop with some delay. But the state of the array is only updated once. I don't understand what's wrong with it. Is this way wrong for updating the state in react?

I'm updating the state of array inside useEffect() and I'm calling the bubbleSort() by "onClick" event

```
import {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'

function App() {

  let count = 0;
  const [array, setArray] = useState([])
  const barBoundary = useRef(null)

  useEffect(()=>{
    count = 0;
    setArray(generateArray(1,100,400))
  }, [])


  const generateArray = (min, max,l) => {
    return Array.from({length: l}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min));
  }

  const sleep = (milli) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milli)
  }

  const bubbleSort = async (speed) => {
    let temp = [...array];
    let len = array.length;
    let checked;
    do {
        checked = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (temp[i] > temp[i + 1]) {
              
              let tmp = temp[i];
              temp[i] = temp[i + 1];
              temp[i + 1] = tmp;
              await sleep(10)
              setArray(temp)
              checked = true;   
            }
            
        }
    } while (checked);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <div className="container">
        <div className="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><button onClick={()=> setArray(generateArray(1,100,700))}>Bubble Sort</button></li>
            <li><button onClick={()=>bubbleSort()}>Sort</button></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="bar-container">
          <div className="bar-boundary" ref={barBoundary}>
            <div className="bars">
              {
                array.map(item => {
                  return(
                  <div className="bar" key={++count}
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor:"blue",
                      height:`${item}%`,
                    }}
                  >
                  </div>)
                })
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: where are you initializing your array? does your array contains any value?

Comment: I'm setting the state of the array inside useEffect(). The values inside the arrays are being generated by a random value generating method.

Comment: can you share useEffect and code from where you are calling bubbelsort function?

Comment: I've edited the question. Please take a look.

Comment: you're missing a closing paren here: `return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milli)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the issue, your array is referring to the same instance and does not re-render. Create a new array from `temp` array and set the state. It worked.

```
setArray([...temp])
```

Comment: @Mayank, check this out !!